# Bind to ContentPage Title From ControlTemplate

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a fairly simple `Xamarin.Forms` App, with a `ContentPage` and a `ControlTemplate` in an `App.Xaml` `ResourceDictionary`

I am trying to bind to the `ContentPage.Title` Property of the parent ContentPage. however the following doesn't seem to work..

**ContentPage**

```
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Inhouse.Mobile.Pcl.Views.MoveLocationView"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource MainPageTemplate}"
    Title="Move Location"
    ...
```

**ControlTemplate**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application
    x:Class="Inhouse.Mobile.Pcl.App"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="MainPageTemplate">

                <cut for Brevity ...>

                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#333333">
                        <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Page.Title}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>

                    <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" >
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    </ScrollView>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I'm not sure what i should actually be binding too

i.e my attempt was

```
<Label Text="{TemplateBinding Page.Title}"></Label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was that i was in a `StackLayout` and needed to set

`HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"` so i could see it.

Additionally, `Title` was sufficient

```
{TemplateBinding Title}
```

I.e

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#333333">
   <Label Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" TextColor="AliceBlue" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```